# Session Not working with JSONP calls in IE and Mobile Safari in ASP.MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, jsonp

I have MVC application and our clients are sending their requests from their websites using JSONP ajax call with the code we provided.

When we browse their websites on Chrome and Firefox, MVC app can keep the session info, but when you browse the website from IE (any version) and mobile Safari MVC apps treats every request as new request.. I am not sure this is front end or backend issue (since everything works fine in Chrome and FF I thought it is front end related)

Here is the codes:

In our web.config file we have this to allow CORS from anywhere:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

this is the JSONP call function we provided to our clients

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<OUR API>?callback=?",
    data: {
        <OUR VARIABLES>
    },
    beforeSend: setHeader,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {}
})

function setHeader(xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
}
```

This is the C# code that handles backend

```
public class ClientController : Controller, IRequiresSessionState
{
    //
    // GET: /
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public string Index()
    {
         if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["test-var"] != null)
            return "you are here before " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["test-var"] = "hi";
        return "you are new";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the attribute [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]

```
public class ClientController : Controller, IRequiresSessionState
{
//
// GET: /
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string Index()
{
     if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["test-var"] != null)
        return "you are here before " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["test-var"] = "hi";
    return "you are new";
}
```

Comment: Just tried, no luck! I was thinking it is related with Session Cookies, somehow Chrome and FF let the MVC app create session cookie whereas IE cant do it, not sure..